# How do I point to the admin artist link correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want my artist links to look like this:

```
http://admin.foobar.com/artists/123
http://www.foobar.com/123
```

My `Routes` setup looks like this:

```
class AdminSubDomain
  def matches?(request)
    whitelists = IpPermission.whitelists

    if whitelists.map { |whitelist| whitelist.ip }.include? request.remote_ip
      request.subdomain == 'admin'
    else
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
  end
end

Foobar::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints AdminSubDomain.new do
    ..
    resources :artists, :only => [:index, :show], :controller => 'admin/artists'
  end

  get ':id' => 'artists#show', :as => 'artist' do
    ..
  end
end
```

`Rake routes` returns:

```
artist GET    /artists/:id(.:format)        admin/artists#show
artist GET    /:id(.:format)                artists#show
```

At the moment, `<%= link_to 'Show', artist_path(artist, :subdomain => :admin) %>` points to: `http://admin.foobar.dev:3000/123`.

It should look like: `http://admin.foobar.dev:3000/artists/123`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the same name (`artist`) for both routes, so when you call `artist_path`, you get the last one you've defined, which is: `get ':id' = 'artists#show', :as => 'artist' do ...`.

Use a different name for the admin route to distinguish it:

```
constraints AdminSubDomain.new do
  ..
  resources :artists, :only => [:index, :show], :controller => 'admin/artists', :as => 'admin_artists'
end
```

Then you can call it with: `<%= link_to 'Show', admin_artist_path(artist, :subdomain => :admin) %>`.

Comment: What about the route that's supposed to point to admin artist index? I think its supposed to be `:as => 'admin_artists'`, plural form